# Difference between $("#id").load and $.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know what is the difference between `$("#id").load` and `$.ajax`?

Comment: for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870086/difference-between-ajax-and-get-and-load

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Let me clarify things for you a little bit :

`$.ajax()` is the basic and low-level ajax function jQuery provides which means you can do what ever you want to like you can work with `XmlHttpRequest` object. But once upon a time jQuery Developers thought that actually besides `$.ajax()`, they could provide more specific methods to developers so they wouldn't need to pass more parameters to make `$.ajax()` method work the way they want. For example they said instead of passing `json` as a parameter to `$.ajax()` to indicate return data type, they provided `$.getJSON()` so we would all know that the return type we expected was `json`, or instead of indicating send method as `post` or `get`, you could use `$.post()` or `$.get()` respectively.

So `load()` is the same thing, it can help you inject html data into your html. with `load()` method you know that an html portion is being expected.

Isn't that cool ?

I think I've been fallen in love.

For more information, you can visit jquery.com, they are even providing their new library and api tutorial page.

**Edit :**

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

is the same as below :

```
$.post("some.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
   function(data){
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });
```

Now as you can see it is the simplified version of `$.ajax()`, to make post call, you need to pass some information of send method type which is `post` as shown at the first example but instead of doing this you can use `$.post()` because you know what you are doing is `post` so this version is more simplified and easy to work on.

But don't forget something. Except for `load()`, all other ajax methods return XHR (XmlHttpRequest instance) so you can treat them as if you were working with XmlHttpRequest, actually you are working with it tho :) and but `load()` returns jQuery which means :

```
$("#objectID").load("test.php", { 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"] } );
```

in the example above, you can easly inject the return html into `#objectID` element. Isn't it cool ? If it wasn't returning jQuery, you should have been working with callback function where you probably get the result out of like `data` object and inject it manually into the html element you want. So it would be hassle but with `$.load()` method, it is really simplified in jQuery.

```
$("#feeds").load("feeds.php", {limit: 25}, function(){
   alert("The last 25 entries in the feed have been loaded");
 });
```

You can even post parameters, so according to those parameters you can do some work at server-side and send html portion back to the client and your cute jQuery code takes it and inject it into `#feeds` html element in the example right above.

Comment: thanks mate that was a perfect description. so .getJSON and .post and .get are all ajax calls too huh? nice!

Comment: yeap.. they are all ajax calls, more simplified versions of `$.ajax()`

Comment: I've made some improvement at my post, maybe it can even help you more. Glad to help you.

Comment: An excellent and concise explanation, SO needs more stuff like this.

Comment: getJSON doesn't add content-type to its requests

Comment: Actually yeah but default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", which is fine for most cases. So normally people don't end up defining this as well. But it depends on the solution tho :) thanks for reminding us.

Comment: @damiien: i agree with you, aaron, you should maintain a blog :)

Answer (score 20):

[`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) initiates an Ajax request to retrieve HTML that, when returned, is set to the given selector.

All the [jQuery Ajax functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) are simply wrappers for [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) so:

```
$("#id").load(...);
```

is probably equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "...",
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data) {
    $("#id").html(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: what does this do?  $("#id").html(data)?
does it overwrite the .innerHtml with the 'data'?

Comment: so with .load at least you dont need to offer a success/failed methods... am i right?

Comment: Yes. html() is equivalent to element.innerHTML = "...". load() offers a success callback option (see the page linked above) but no failure hook.

Answer (score 4):

A more concise summary and the most important difference is that `$.ajax` allows you to set `content-type` and `datatype`.

These two are important for making JSON requests, or XML requests. ASP.NET is more fussy with a missing content-type field (atleast when you use `[WebMethod]`) and will simply return the HTML of the page instead of JSON.

`$.load()` is intended to simply return straight HTML. `$.ajax` also gives you

- caching
- error handling
- filtering of data
- password

plus others.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation ...

[`$(selector).load(..)`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load)

> Load HTML from a remote file and inject it into the DOM.

[`$.ajax(...)`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax)

> Load a remote page using an HTTP request. This is jQuery's low-level AJAX implementation.

`load` is specifically for fetching (via GET unless parameters are provided, then POST is used) an HTML page and directly inserting it into the selected nodes (those selected by the `$(selector)` portion of `$(selector).load(...)`.

`$.ajax(...)` is a more general method that allows you to make GET and POST requests, and does nothing specific with the response.

I encourage you to read the documentation.

Comment: if .load is async, then is it using xhtmlrequestobject as well?

Comment: which is the best documentation on this? is it the jquery website?

Comment: All remote requests in jQuery use HttpXmlRequest or the Active X control depending on the environment.  And yes, the jquery documentation is the best documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the source code for the `load` function: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L15

As you can see, it's a `$ajax` with some options handling. In other words, a convenience method.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer may not be valid anymore in light of the use of deferred and promise objects. I believe that with .ajax you can use .when but you cannot do so with .load. In short, I believe that .ajax is more powerful than .load. For example:

```
      some_promise = $.ajax({....});
      .when(some_promise).done(function(){.... });
```

You get more granular control over the html loading. There is also .fail and .always for failure and "no matter what" cases. You don't get this in load. Hope I am correct on this.