# Jquery reload current tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I use Jquery 1.4.2. Below is the code that uses tabs.

```
   <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#unit"><span>Unit Information</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#documents"><span>Documents</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#x"><span>x</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#y"><span>y</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="unit"></div>
      <div id="documents">
         <input type="button" id="add_file" onclick="add_file()" />
         <table>
           <tr>
             <td>ID</td>
             <td>File Name</td>
           </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
      <div id="x"></div>
      <div id="y"></div>
    </div>
```

When I run the command

```
$('#tabs').tabs('option','selected')
```

it correctly shows the tabIndex.

But

```
$('#tabs').tabs('load',1)
```

does not seem to work at all. It is not reloading the tab content.

Is this a Jquery version problem?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to make happen via the 'load' command? It may be possible to do what you want another way.

Comment: I'm trying to add a document in the documents tab and once it is added I want to reload the tab so that it shows the updated list of documents

Comment: @thenewseattle That is not what I'm looking for. I have a tab which has an add document button and a table that lists uploaded files. I just want to reload the tab every time a file is uploaded.

Comment: @thenewseattle agreed and thanks for what you did... I've edited my post if that helps you to get a clearer picture

Comment: @thenewseattle no I do not

Comment: @Ravi you can go to jsfiddle.net and write your codes and send us the link so we can investigate codes faster

Comment: alright.. let us take the link that you sent as an example(for some reason you seem to have removed the link and the comment). You add a new tab in that. My question is how do you reload a specific tab ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, it is not the jQuery version that is the problem. With all due respect, your design is incorrect. However, since you are using version 1.4.2 of jQuery, you should be aware that [you must use jQueryUI 1.8.24 or less](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI#Release_history). Therefore:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
```

Back to your question. Since you are uploading a file, then you are POSTing the file (probably via a form, or better yet AJAX) to another PHP file. Javascript won't have a chance to show it.

What will work (and for everything to happen/display the way you want) is to add the document using AJAX. You can do it manually, or I can recommend one of these plugins:

- http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php (used in the example below)
- http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/

Just to prove my point, though, in the following example I emulated "adding a file" using js/jQ. As you can see in the demo, the new data appears just fine.

<kbd>[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A7wr9/)</kbd>

```
$('#add_file').click(function() {
    $('#documents').find('table').append('<tr><td>002</td><td>another_file.doc</td></tr>');
});
```

---

See these SO posts for some simple examples of how AJAX works:

- [Place PHP results inside HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221813/place-php-results-inside-html-page/17221883#17221883)
- [A simple AJAX example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734395/form-inside-of-load-not-posting-correctly/13734466#13734466)
- [More complicated example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887098/two-post-requests-one-after-the-other-second-post-request-doesnt-get-execut/17887642#17887642)
- [Populate dropdown 2 based on selection in dropdown 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924082/dynamic-drop-down-box/16924652#16924652)

*Please upvote any posts that you find helpful.*

Below is a code example of what you want to do. The example works, but I am disappointed to see not with your versions of jQuery/jQueryUI sadly. Please try the example (copy/paste code into a .PHP document on your web server) with the current version and then again with the 1.4.2/1.8.24 versions -- current version works fine. (You can switch between versions easily by uncommenting/comment the obvious tags in the head) If nothing else, perhaps you can use this working example as a starting point, at the least.

**Note that I did not do anything on the back end to receive/process the uploaded file.** I had to cut the example somewhere, so did not write the back-end processing files. But here is a link where you can see an example: http://hayageek.com/ajax-file-upload-jquery/ (*scroll down to section "Server Side"*)

---

**Fully Working Example: Just copy/paste into PHP doc on your server **

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<!--
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
-->

    <link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.uploadfile/2.0.7/css/uploadfile.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.uploadfile/2.0.7/js/jquery.uploadfile.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="//getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

        <style>
            *, body {font-size:12px;}
            table, th, td, tr {border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid lightgrey;}
            th {background:lightgrey;border:1px solid grey;}
            td {height:25px;}
            th.id {width:30px;}
            th.fn {width:125px;}
            #add_file{margin-bottom:15px;}
            .fn {width:200px;height:30px;padding:5px;}
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var cnt = 2;

                $('#tabs').tabs();
                $('#add_file').button(); //for visual appearance only
                $('#dox').click(); //auto-open the Documents tab for convenience

                //init dialog box
                $('#addbox').dialog({
                    autoOpen:false,
                    title: "Add File:"
                }); //END #addbox.dialog


                $('#add_file').click(function() {
                    //Invisibly upload your file to the server
                    var uploadObj = $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
                        url: "name_of_php_file_that_receives_your_uploaded_doc.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        allowedTypes:"xls,doc,pdf",
                        fileName: "myfile",
                        multiple: false,
                        autoSubmit: true,
                        showStatusAfterSuccess:false,
                        onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr) {
                            upfilename = $('.ajax-file-upload-filename').html();
                            upfilename = upfilename.split(' ')[1];
                            upfilename = upfilename.split('<')[0];
                            $('#documents').find('table').append('<tr><td>00'+cnt+'</td><td>' +upfilename+ '</td></tr>');
                            $('#addbox').html('');
                            $('#addbox').dialog('destroy');

                            //Add filename and any other data to your MySQL database
                            $.ajax({
                                type:'POST',
                                url: 'your_functions_file_on_server.php',
                                data:'func_name=insert_file_into_db&upfilename=' + upfilename
                            });
                        },
                    });

                    //Open dialog box to display the Add File controls. Although appearing to come
                    //AFTER the #addbox.destroy code, this happens first. The "Upload" button that
                    //launches the entire process is actually in your jQUI #addbox dialog, which 
                    //gets opened NOW... As soon as that button is pressed, the ^above^ code runs.
                    $('#addbox').dialog('open');
                }); //END #addfile.click


            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#unit"><span>Unit Information</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#documents" id="dox"><span>Documents</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#x"><span>x</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#y"><span>y</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="unit"></div>
        <div id="documents">
            <input type="button" id="add_file" value="Add File" />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th class="id">ID</th>
                    <th class="fn">File Name</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>001</td>
                    <td>myfile.doc</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="x"></div>
        <div id="y"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="addbox">
        <div id="fileuploader"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that is a very detailed answer. thanks for that. I'm aware of the AJAX approach and that is how I did it. It is just that I'd come across the reloading tab stuff using the line of code as mentioned in the question and wondered why it didn't work in my case.

Comment: Sorry, Ravi, I guess I didn't understand the question then. I'm afraid I still don't understand what is going on over on your side. This is where it would be great to have a jsFiddle that could also do ajax...  (Ah, if only...)

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding... What I meant was that as you know we've two options. One using the AJAX approach and the other is my original question. Now, I've done it using AJAX to reload the div but I would've liked to do it using the $('#tabs').load(etc..)... code.

Comment: In fact, they are the same. $.load is (like $.get and $.post) just another wrapper for $.ajax. The difference is that the three above methods are more restricted. The (perceived) advantage to using them is for a shorter code block, that is all. But all four call $.ajax under the hood. Same code gets run, no matter how it looks on the surface. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250630/difference-between-load-and-ajax-functions-in-jquery) and this one -- [in particular, look at Cletus' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076642/difference-between-id-load-and-ajax).

Comment: However, do also note that .load() does not work with the new and very useful: .when(), .always(), .fail(). Therefore, $.ajax should be your fallback