# $.ajax vs $.post vs $.get vs $.load

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between $.ajax() and $.get() and $.load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870086/difference-between-ajax-and-get-and-load)

What I'm trying to accomplish is to change the data in the page without refreshing the page. By going through the documentation of jQuery I understand that I can use below methods. But I don't understand which method to use. They all look the same to me.

**What's the difference between $.ajax vs $.post vs $.get vs $.load ?**

I read the documentation but I couldn't get the proper understanding of the difference of the above methods. I'm new to jQuery. If someone can please explain the difference, that would be a great help.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I will read that threat too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They do what they say they do.

- $.ajax is the function used to send XMLHttpRequests
- $.post is a POST wrapper for $.ajax
- $.get is a GET wrapper for $.ajax
- $.load is the same concept, but allows you to load the content into a selected element easily.

Answer (score 4):

$.post and $.get are just shorthand for using $.ajax with a specified type. The same applies to load as well.

[Difference between $("#id").load and $.ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076642/difference-between-id-load-and-ajax)

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ - It actually specifies it's a shorthand in like the second paragraph:

> This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:
>
> `$.ajax({
>     type: 'POST',   url: url,   data: data,   success: success,
>
>   dataType: dataType });`

Answer (score 2):

[`post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), and [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) are all shorthand wrappers for the [`ajax` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> The $.ajax() function underlies all Ajax requests sent by jQuery. It
>   is often unnecessary to directly call this function, as several
>   higher-level alternatives like $.get() and .load() are available and
>   are easier to use. If less common options are required, though,
>   $.ajax() can be used more flexibly.