# Update html content in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to update divs by html pages.I have used Ajax.Updater and jquery .load() .These are good.Can anyone suggest someother methods?? I want to show html pages in some div.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify : Are `Ajax.Updater` and `jquery.load()` not enough for you ?

Comment: Yes,but I want to know other options too.

Answer (score 3):

For me the best way to dynamically generated content is via Jquery. For your problem, so I think the following code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#ContentPage').load('MyPage.html');
}
```

Comment: Yes,But it will load from cache.SO changes wont be easily available

Answer (score 1):

jQuerys `.load()` is the best option as far as im concerned.

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 1):

**Ajax.Updater and jquery .load() are best**.

If you are curious you can try

```
   $.ajax({
    url: 'page.html',
    dataType: 'html',
    timeout: 5000, // 5 seconds
    success: function(html) {
    $("#myDiv").html(html);
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you always using $.ajax function over $.load for that purposes. The reason is that $.load is using cache, which cannot be disabled with parameters while defining it - the only way to disable caching for  $.load is to disable it globally for all ajax calls.

After all, $.load is just a wrapper for $.ajax

[Globally disable cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168963/stop-jquery-load-response-from-being-cached)

[load vs ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076642/difference-between-id-load-and-ajax)

I am not sure about ajax updater vs ajax, will check and update answer...