# pause event while function runs

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am writing an infinite scroll function and having it run if the `$(window).scrollTop()` is almost as large as the documents height, and it works perfectly...

The issue is that it takes a couple seconds for the new posts to load, and in that time, if the page was scrolled, the function was called multiple times before the document got larger and therefore did not load the posts the way I intented.

**Can I add a line to a function that will pause a specific event (in this case the `scroll` event) until the function has finished executing?**

```
function f(){
    //stop $(window).scroll
    //execute code
    //allow $(window).scroll
}
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(condition){
        f();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/) did a post on this awhile ago

Here is the code he used

```
didScroll = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
     didScroll = true;
 });

setInterval(function() {
    if ( didScroll ) {
      didScroll = false;
      // Check your page position and then
      // Load in more results
   }
}, 250);
```

Comment: This nearly works, but it's still giving me some troubble...but good for now...maybe I should switch from .load to .ajax

Comment: [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076642/difference-between-id-load-and-ajax "Post") that may help you choose which to use

Comment: I ended up using this with load! It works perfectly as long as the delay is between 500-1000. I just added a loading message as well as have it start firing earlier

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.off` to unbind an event, but I would recommend to just use a variable to keep track if its been triggered or not.

This snippet will prevent f from being called until the `scrolling` has been set to false again.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(this.scrolling == undefined)
        this.scrolling = false;

    if(this.scrolling == false){
        this.scrolling = true;
        f();
    }
});

function f(){
    //execute code
    window.scrolling = false;
}
```

Comment: @RyanSaxe make sure that window.scrolling = false; is in the ajax callback and not in the function that calls the ajax request. The code will continue to execute and enable the scrolling event before the new post was downloaded and inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the scroll event once it's called, then reattach it if/when the load posts request is completed:

```js
function loadPosts() {
    if (condition) { // e.g. scrollTop almost equal to document height.
        $(window).off('scroll', loadPosts);
        $('[selector]').load('[URL-to-posts]', function(posts) {
            bindScroll();
            // Display posts.
        });
    }
}

// Binds the scroll event.
function bindScroll() {
    $(window).on('scroll', loadPosts);
}

$(bindScroll); // Call on document ready.
```

Comment: I'm using `.load', not '.ajax'...is there a significant reason other than more functionality for ajax over load?

Comment: @RyanSaxe `load` is fine; `ajax` is a lower-level function that gives you a lot more control, but there's no reason to use it directly if you don't need it. (`load` calls `ajax` behind-the-scenes.) The important thing is that rebinding the scroll event in the callback means that it won't happen until the request completes.