# jquery load vs ajax for form post submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

If all I want to do is submit a form to a PHP processor with POST data and get the result, is there any reason to use the ajax method over the jQuery load method?

Using Ajax requires a bunch of code versus something very simple on one line in jQuery like this:

```
$("#myDIV").load("myProcessor.php", {field1: target.value});
```

Hmmm, maybe this only works well with one field? Sorry, just getting back into JS.

Comment: Isn't the load method just using Ajax internally? Or do you mean something different by "the ajax method"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(element).load(...)` will automatically insert the server response into the selected element as html ([jQuery documentation for .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)). This might result in your server exposing information about the request directly to the user, which is probably not what you're looking to do.

`$.ajax()` also allows very fine control over what happens during the request. You can accurately intercept exceptions and produce a callback when the request finishes succesfully. These are all reasons to use `$.ajax()` over `$(element).load(...)`. However, if your **only** concern is sending the data in the POST header and working with the response, then using `$.post` with a callback function will probably be the simplest approach. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

- The `.load` method is is *roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data,
  success)* ([src](http://api.jquery.com/load/)).
- The `.get` method  *is a shorthand Ajax
  function* ([src](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)).

For a simple ajax call, .load is appropriate. Use `.ajax` if you want to deal with specials parameters.

PS: If you don't want a fat framework like jQuery, look here : http://microjs.com/#ajax

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery website about load

> This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is
>   roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success) except that it is a
>   method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback
>   function. When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus
>   is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML contents of the
>   matched element to the returned data.

you can read [difference between load ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076642/difference-between-id-load-and-ajax) on StackOverflow.

But, `load` is not for submitting a form using `post` method. Both `POST` and `GET` are different methods and works differently, data submitted using `GET` method will be available in the `$_GET` array but not in the `$_POST`.