# get contents with ajax and display them directly without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have created a blog in php. For each comment the user can press a Favorite/Unfavorite button (if want) to Favorite/Unfavorite a post. My button works perfect. The only problem I got is that when user press Favorite/Unfavorite... I dont get the number of Favorites/Unfavorites for this post. In order to get this, each time I have to refressh the page. Some people told me that I need to use Ajax in order to do this.

I use table likes, to hold favorites for each post: **likes(like_id, user, the_comment_id)**
I use table comments for aeach post: **comments(comments_id, comment, user)**

This is my php code:

```
<?php

$comment_id = $row['comments_id'];

// ... code above

//button for favorite and unfavorite
 $get_button = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM `likes` WHERE `user`='$session_user_id' AND `the_comment_id`='{$row['comments_id']}'  ");                    
 $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_button);

if($get==""){   
    $comments .= "<a role='button' class='button' id='like$comment_id'  style='color:grey;'>Favorite</a>";
}else if($get!=""){
    $comments .= "<a role='button' class='button' id='unlike$comment_id' style='color:grey;'>Unfavorite</a>";
}

// place favorites for this comment here
$comments .= " $total_favorites ";

?>
```

This is my jquery:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#like<?php echo $comment_id; ?>").click(function() { 
  var id = "<?php echo $comment_id; ?>";
  $.post("parse.php",{like:id}, function(data){

   $("#like<?php echo $comment_id; ?>");
   $(".button<?php echo $comment_id; ?>").html(data);

  });
  $(this).hide().attr("Disabled", "True").text("Favorite done!").show();
});


$("#unlike<?php echo $comment_id; ?>").click(function() { 

  var id = "<?php echo $comment_id; ?>";
  $.post("parse.php",{unlike:id}, function(data){

   $("#unlike<?php echo $comment_id; ?>");
   $(".button<?php echo $comment_id; ?>").html(data);

});     
$(this).hide().attr("Disabled", "True").text("Unfavorite done!").show();
 });

});

</script>
```

This is my parse.php code:

```
<?php  

if(isset($_POST['like'])){
 $id = $_POST['like'];      
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO likes VALUES ('', '$session_user_id', '$id') "); 
}


if(isset($_POST['unlike'])){
 $id = $_POST['unlike'];
 mysql_query(" DELETE FROM likes WHERE `user`='$session_user_id' AND `the_comment_id`='$id'  ");
}


$favorites = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM `likes` WHERE `the_comment_id`='{$row['comments_id']}'  ");    
$total_favorites = mysql_num_rows($favorites);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to return something from the `parse.php` script. The `data` variable will not contain the count unless you either echo it out directly or return JSON and parse in your jQuery function prior to setting the `.html(data)` values.

Comment: any idea how to do this?

Comment: See the examples attached to answer below: just use **echo**. For example, write: `echo "Found " . $total_favorites . " favorites in the database.";`

Comment: Or, better yet, create a variable containing all the code you wish to return: `$out = "<h1>Favs</h1><p>Found " .$total_favorites. "favorites"; echo $out;`

Answer (score 1):

You are right, AJAX is the way to go. Note that AJAX is known by multiple names:

- XMLHttpRequest -- javascript
- AJAX
- `$.ajax()` -- the jQuery superset
- `$.get()` -- a shortcut to `$.ajax()` with `TYPE: "GET"`
- `$.post()` -- a shortcut to `$.ajax()` with `TYPE: "POST"`
- `$.load()` -- see [Difference between $("#id").load and $.ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076642/difference-between-id-load-and-ajax)

Here are some examples that will get you started on AJAX:

[A simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734395/form-inside-of-load-not-posting-correctly/13734466#13734466)

[More complicated example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887098/two-post-requests-one-after-the-other-second-post-request-doesnt-get-execut/17887642#17887642)

[Populate dropdown 2 based on selection in dropdown 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924082/dynamic-drop-down-box/16924652#16924652)

Answer (score 1):

Further to what Lucas said, change your code to look like this:

```
<?php  

    if(isset($_POST['like'])){
        $id = $_POST['like'];      
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO likes VALUES ('', '$session_user_id', '$id') "); 
    }

    if(isset($_POST['unlike'])){
        $id = $_POST['unlike'];
        mysql_query(" DELETE FROM likes WHERE `user`='$session_user_id' AND `the_comment_id`='$id'  ");
    }

    $favorites = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM `likes` WHERE `the_comment_id`='{$row['comments_id']}'  ");    
    $total_favorites = mysql_num_rows($favorites);
    
    $out = '<h1>Found In Database</h1>';
    $out .= '<p>You received ' .$total_favorites. ' favorites.';

    echo $out;
?>
```

Comment: thats ok i understant what is have to change in my parse php file. Any idea how to change now my jquery script and how to add ajax inside it?

Comment: You are using AJAX -- $.post() is AJAX. However, I will look again at your code.

Comment: @user2491321 I created another answer for the revised jQuery code

Comment: A quick heads up for readers: this code contains SQL injection vulnerabilities, and is dangerous to use. It looks like it was copied from the original post. Always use parameter binding when accessing a relational database, unless it is unavailable, in which case untaint or escape values with care.

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't work, then please post the relevant HTML so that we can accurately target your DOM elements:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("[id^=like]").click(function() { 
        var window.id = $(this).attr('id').split['e'][1];
        $.post("parse.php",{like:id}, function(data){
            $("#like"+id).find(".button").html(data);
        }); //END .post
        $(this).hide().attr("Disabled", "True").text("Favorite done!").show();
    }); //END like.click


    $("[id^=unlike]").click(function() { 
        var window.id = $(this).attr('id').split['e'][1];
        $.post("parse.php",{unlike:id}, function(data){
            $("#unlike"+id).find(".button").html(data);
        }); //END .post
        $(this).hide().attr("Disabled", "True").text("Unfavorite done!").show();
    }); //END #unlike.click

});
```

Notes:

1. We use `$("[id^=unlike]")` as the selector - this means: get the DOM element with an ID that **starts with** "unlike"
2. `$(this).attr('id').split['e'][1]` means:
    a. Get the ID attribute ("like5" or "unlike123")
    b. Break it into an array at teh 'e' char:  `lik` and `5` -or- `unlik` and `123`
    c. Grab the 2nd array element (the number: 5 or 123)
    d. Stick it in a *global* variable called `id`

Comment: my only html code for button I use are at the top of code posted in my main php file: <a role='button' class='button' id='like$comment_id'  style='color:grey;'>Favorite</a> and   <a role='button' class='button' id='unlike$comment_id' style='color:grey;'>Unfavorite</a>

Comment: In your first php code block, you are building a PHP variable called `$comments` - but you never echo it out the screen. How does it appear on the screen? If it does not, then just do `echo $comments;` to see it on screen.

Comment: ok yes you are right. $comments .=".$row['comment'].";  it gets the row of comment from table comments.