# when to use ajax.load() or jquery.ajax()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am little confused about in what scenario `Ajax.load()` method is used and what scenario `jQuery.ajax()` is used.

There are many [AJAX](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery--net-6289) method, I am mainly confused between [ajax.load()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp) and [simple ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajax)

Comment: i assume you mean [`$(element).load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load)? please use the [official jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com)! [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: It is duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076642/difference-between-id-load-and-ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `load` function is specifically used for loading in  content from another page, into an element on your current page.

The other two functions are general-ajax functions that jQuery provides. Also, `.get()` is just shorthand for sending a `$_GET` request via AJAX.