# Load a html into a div - which one should be used at what situation?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

To load a html page into a div

```
1) HTML Embedded Object Element

2) Jquery load

3) Ajax
```

Which one should be used and when should be used?
Because we can achieve this by using any one of these three options. But I am not clear what should be used in what situations?

Comment: Refer this you may get some idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076642/difference-between-id-load-and-ajax

Answer (score 2):

**1) HTML Embedded Object Element**

You can use `embed` to add rich content, like videos, images, pdfs, etc.

**2) Jquery load**

You can use `.load()` when you want `html`, `json`, `xml` or any other content, and an advantage of `.load()` is that you can select wich portion of the page you would like to load.

A difference between `load` and `embed` is that **you** determine when the data is loaded, if you embed an object it will be loaded when the page loads (and can also cause page load issues because of that).

**3) Ajax**

Is behind the scenes exactly the same as `.load()`, but depending on the exact situation `load()` might be more convenient, and `ajax` more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Embedd when you are getting data from a third party, EX: youtube video, soundloud song, etc...

and load ajax if you are loading non formated html data (IE: json or xml).